# URL regex without several paths

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot

I have the WebMvcConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers (ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/{path:(?!api|res).*}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
    }
}
```

I need to redirect every request to index.html except paths /api/... and /res/...
Can not create appropriate regex, I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Perhaps `{path:^(?!(?:api|res)/)}` or `{path:^(?!(?:api|res)/).*}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!(\/path\/+|\/res\/+)).*$
```

This Regex matches if the string doesn't start with `/path/` or `/res/`.